# data.table Repeat conditional Value by id

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table like this:

```
library(data.table)
group <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a")
id <- c("1232","1232","1232","1232","1232","1232")
response <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
score <- c(2,1,3,4,2,5)

df <- cbind.data.frame(group,id,response,score)
setDT(df)

 group   id response score
     a 1232        a     2
     a 1232        b     1
     a 1232        c     3
     a 1232        d     4
     a 1232        e     2
     a 1232        f     5
```

Score only applies for rows where response is 'a'.  I would like to create something like this where the score shows for every row by id:

```
  group   id response score ares
     a 1232        a     2  2
     a 1232        b     1  2
     a 1232        c     3  2
     a 1232        d     4  2
     a 1232        e     2  2
     a 1232        f     5  2
```

I've tried creating a row index and pulling only the rows for the a responses then joining that back to the original data table by the id, however, this is seems pretty inefficient.  Is there a way to use just the data.table syntax to avoid an expensive join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `id` and then assign the conditional value (score where response is `a`) to the new column:

```
df[, ares := score[response == 'a'][1], id][]

#   group   id response score ares
#1:     a 1232        a     2    2
#2:     a 1232        b     1    2
#3:     a 1232        c     3    2
#4:     a 1232        d     4    2
#5:     a 1232        e     2    2
#6:     a 1232        f     5    2
```

Depending on your actual data, you may also simply do `df[, ares := score[response == 'a'], id][]`. Just notice that the first option pick the first score if there are multiple responses as `a` and the second option will cycle all the scores where responses are equal to `a`.